# Get a string from a .NET exe using CIL opcodes?

Tags: string, hex, cil

I was wondering if there's any way to pull a string from an exe?
I've been able to pull int32 values etc. but I'm confused on how I would do the same for pulling a string.
I know the opcode for ldstr is 0x72 but I can't seem to convert the data after that.

Here's the hex:

```
72 96 02 00 70
```

So how can I convert 96 02 00 70 to a string? I can get the ASCII for it but I need the literal string that you can find in a disassembler. It seems a little short to be a string though (possibly a location of a string? I'm kind of new to this). 
The CIL for this is (from IDA):

```
ldstr "Car Grip Disabled"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: It is a metadata token.  You use it to index the metadata tables.  "How do I write a disassembler" is not on topic here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that then. I'm actually just writing a tool that skims values from other tools that aren't obfuscated, not a full disassembler. The strings are vital though as they give context to the other values skimmed.

Comment: I can't find any resources online that describe how I would go about accessing the metadata tables... hmm..

Comment: @user3530525 Have you looked at [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf)?

Comment: Reading it now, I've found out where the strings are. They are in the <Module> section. I just can't find out how I can pull a string from it using the metadata token. I'll keep looking, thanks for posting that.

Comment: Why aren't you just using something like Mono.Cecil, that will do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Module.ResolveString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.resolvestring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. It finds a string in the string sections of a module by its token. In this case, the token is 1879048854.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using .NET ?

Comment: @user3530525 You mean without an application that requires .NET? I don't think it is possible, but there is a [`_Module`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices._module%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) COM interface. It might have some methods for that.

Comment: Yeah I was basically making a disassembler for .NET PE files a while back. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Well, it is probably possible to manually search the module section, but I don't know any specifications of it or the relation to the metadata tokens.